# Join us for #MageStackDay on Feburary 3rd and 4th 2017

Tags: discussion, event, magestackday

**We're back!**
The MageStackDay #6 will happen on February 3rd & 4th!

MageStackDay is an online hackathon dedicated to **answering, closing and cleaning up questions** on magento.stackexchange.com. The goal will be to get the answered questions rate up by at least a few percent and get more users active on this platform.

Please help us spreading the word about #MageStackDay on twitter, IRC, facebook groups, developer events and wherever you meet people willing to join us for this event!

More information: http://www.magestackday.com

Sign up [here](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc0OUJ-EKW7I5bn32qVErGff4jLpHPYQodJ-0knc_WsB3Gd4w/viewform).

Comment: https://twitter.com/magestackday/status/816660476033527808

Comment: yup.. i will join again

Comment: sure............

Comment: I am in.........

Comment: Thumbs Up...........

Comment: I will join for the first time , may I will enjoy :)

Comment: I am sure you will enjoy, @Murtuza!

Comment: sweet! last one was my start on mage.stacks, hope to really help out this go around

Comment: So how long till it starts? Keep this open on your screen and you will always know: http://itsalmo.st/#magestackday

Comment: @AnnaVölkl How to join in magestackday?

Comment: Hi @Rakesh, please use the sign up form (also linked on our website): https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc0OUJ-EKW7I5bn32qVErGff4jLpHPYQodJ-0knc_WsB3Gd4w/viewform

Comment: @AnnaVölkl I have already sign up this form.

Comment: I sent out an invite to our magestackday slack team today.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl, do you want us to sign up on the google doc even if we are already on the slack channel?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @circlesix: Yes, please sign up anyway :) Thanks!

Comment: Next time .....