# Feedback to question - is question worth bounty or not?

Tags: discussion, magento2, bounty, unanswered-questions

Why there is no sub forum where users can link their posts (x date old without answer) before adding bounty to them. Maybe users would like to have discussion (what other members of the forum think about the question and how to improve it) before adding bounty? At least post owner can get a reason why his/her post is without any answer (To find solution to user asked question would take too much time...?).

**Problem to be solved:**

When i post a question and it is without answer three days i start to wonder what is wrong - What ways i have to get answer to that question (how to get at least any improvement suggestion or feedback)?

I am beginner at programming with Magento so i have question to much more experienced programmers. Why there are so many unanswered posts concerning Magento 2? I am really sorry for asking about it, I am just curious what are the reasons why many posts have no answers.

Answer (score 9):

You couldn't have asked this at a better moment than right now. Today the [6th MageStackDay](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1113/3326) has started and the [MageStackDay](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1113/3326) tradition addresses an issue you are running into.

Let's start with stating that there are many many more people asking questions than there are people who provide (quality) answers. That's part of your problem, because that means that it will take some time to get an answer to your question.

Things you can do to form a good question:

- Start at the Magento StackExchange help center: https://magento.stackexchange.com/help
- Specifically read the article "[How do I ask a good question?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" in the help center
- Now, make sure you are providing all the info needed to be able to give an answer: Magento (exact) version, PHP version, web browser+version/webserver+version (if applicable to the issue), **what do you expect it to do? and why?, what are you trying to achieve?**, what have you tried (provide code, provide commands) so far?, explicitly state that you have cleared caches and compilation/generation, etc...
- **Choose the right/proper tags**! People on Magento SE can have set favorite tags they like to answer. Setting only a [magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2) tag doesn't draw anyones attention in particular
- Write a specific question title, not too long, make it as specific as possible, describing the actual problem

I hope this helps you!